# How to do join in hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql, bigdata

Can anyone suggest me how to join four different tables in hive which already exist and I want to remove few columns from each table after join or if possible before join.

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN` is a valid Hive keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly from [hive documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Joins), I provide you an example for a JOIN with three tables:

```
SELECT a.val, b.val, c.val FROM a JOIN b ON (a.key = b.key1) JOIN c ON (c.key = b.key2)
```

You can drop a column using the `ALTER TABLE ... REPLACE COLUMNS` command. Please refer to the [hive documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Add/ReplaceColumns) for this problem, too.